# Word Plugin Desktop version not let me login by AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-js, word-web-addins

I am building Word Plugin, the Word Online seems ok, I login by my "Work or school" account, and my plugin use AzureAD to login, since I already log in Word Online, my plugin just log me in directly (I use Owin OpenIdConnect).

I expect to get the same result for Desktop version of Word, however, it doesn't work. When I clicked "login" button in my plugin, it ask me to "pick up account", when I click my account, it open a web browser shows

"**We couldn't sign you into this application with your user account. Your account may not work with this application, or we may not be able to sign you in automatically right now. Try selecting "Use another account" and then sign in again.**"

If I choose **"Use another account"** to login, it shows below error 
**"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST requests. Received a GET request."**

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Please include a minimum viable code sample showing what your code is attempting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, make sure you always upgrade to the latest Word, the working software version is **Version 1807 (Build 10325.20082)**.